# Azure Pricing Estimate Using Rate Card API?

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

Is there a way to calculate the estimated monthly cost for an Azure virtual machine using the Rate Card API? I've downloaded all of the Rate Card API data and I'm comparing it to the online Azure pricing calculator (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/), and I'm not seeing many matches. I can see a few matches when trying to calculate Windows OS's, but nothing for Linux. Not sure if I'm even looking at the right data.

Comment: Please edit your question and include: 1) What you expect to see and 2) What you are actually seeing. Also include in details the process you're using to compare the values from Rate Card API and pricing calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are comparing the same regions prices and same currency. I`m also using RateCard API here https://azureprice.net/ and the price is very similar to public calc.